# Nestjs Middlware in main.ts get request body

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, middleware

When I'm getting request from frontend, I put log in route handler for example

```
@Post('create')
createPost(
@Body() body: CreatePostDto,
){
  console.log(body); // I'm getting body correctly
}
```

But I want to add bodyParser in main.ts because of parse formData which is all string and I want to get other types which is added from front. So I checked that when I put middleware in main.ts

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.body) //its empty object so why?
})
```

So I have 2 questions.

1. Why in middleware I get empty body?
2. How to parse formdata?

Comment: Express' `bodyparser` doesn't handle `multipart/form-data`: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: Yes it does, you have to set set app.use(urlencoded( extended: true })

Comment: @AdrienDePeretti `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is not the same as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Okay, but I also had questions that, Why in middleware I get empty body?

Comment: `bodyParser` will not work If I got empty object of `req.body`

Answer (score 1):

see https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3148
Your middleware is applied before bodyParser. Instead of using app.use(), you should rather follow this example: https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#applying-middleware, so in your case: